# CSS - Vertical align text

Tags: css

I have a JSFIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo4p489e/3/)

I know this is super simple but I can't get it to work

I just need to centre the text vertically

```
        .pdf-button{
            background: #eee;  
        }

        .pdf-button p{
            display: inline;  
        }

        .pdf-button a{
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 20px;  
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        i{
            color: #aaa;
        }
```

Comment: It's because the icon's height that your text sits on the bottom. You probably want to remove the margin on your `p` tag and do something with line-height.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Should be for `i`, not for `a`

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo4p489e/6/)**